# How to refresh blank bookmark favicons in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-sync, favicon

I encounter a problem which I saw blank favicons in my bookmarks.
I use Windows 7, Version 46.0.2490.86 m.

I searched for other question on this subject and tried their solutions without success.

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking, or how your answer solved this. But at least you have got this working, so maybe that is enough.

Answer (score 0):

What solved my problem is removing the person from google sync and adding it again.

Comment: What person? How does the person relate to a favicon for a bookmarked webpage?

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question so others don't spend time trying to find a solution.  However, as AdamV indicates, it isn't clear how this relates to the question.  It would be more helpful to others with a similar problem if you could expand your answer a little to elaborate.

Comment: Additionally, it would be excellent if you explained what you tried before (that you mentioned in the question) and why that didn't work, but this does. If you can.